# Restrict Duplicate entry in android listview

Tags: android

my Android project is that i have made contact list into Spinner and after that i put one by one my contacts into Listview.i want that my spinner contact will not be repeated in the listview.i want to put some check point before to listview execute.what should i have to do??
   PLEASE HELP ME

Answer (score 1):

Use `java.util.Set`.Set collection not allowed duplicate elements.and its sort way to care for duplicate contact.

```
Set<String> myContactList = new HashSet<String>();
myContactList.add("Name");
```

Comment: actually i m using spinner and beside that one buton is there so may be same contacts would be clicked twice so it would appear twice in listview.

Answer (score 0):

Add contacts to Set. It will take care of duplicate values. Otherwise add contacts to ArrayList and before adding check whether already the contact exist in the list. If exists then dont add.

After adding contact to list, call

adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();